# how to assign default value of checkbox in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

guys, I want to know a thing is possible or not  as described below
supposed have I have 3 thing 
illustration of frontend

```
     <td><input  type="checkbox" v-model="named[0]></td>
     <td><input  type="checkbox" v-model="named[1]></td>
     <td><input  type="checkbox" v-model="named[2]></td>

   fruit list    | checkbox
   ----------------------------
    apple        | checkbox        -> if this clicked passed true else pass false 
    mango        | checkbox        -> if this clicked passed true else pass false 
      orange     | checkbox        -> if this clicked passed true else pass false
```

suppose user clicked  apple and orange checkbox and   clicked on submit then v-model named  should have array value like this 0:true 1:false 3:true is this possible in vue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hello rocky you can try something like this

```
  <input v-model="smoking" true-value="1" false-value="0" type="checkbox">
```

if checkbox is checked then you get  1 else 0 in same array

Comment: you code is working only if i click on checkbox else i m getting empty for that array